# Display UITableView like UIActionsheet style?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiactionsheet

I have been trying to display UITableView like UIActionsheet showFromRect: style. Is there any way to do it programatically or Do I need to use image for that.

Please check the below image...

[image]

Comment: May be use a POPOVER??

Comment: @Divyu Will it give the arrow appearance?

Comment: This is tagged iPhone, not iPad. Therefore you can't use `UIPopoverController`. It's only for use on the iPad.

Comment: @Newbee yes it will give.. I am using my custom class of UIPopOverController for iphone.. It's easy to use and the appropriate way to do it...

Comment: @maddy You also don't get showFromRect for UIActionSheet. (you do, it just shows normally)

Comment: @AdamShiemke That's because the iPhone doesn't support `UIPopoverController`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the link for Custom `UIPopOverController` for iphone.
It will resolve your purpose. :)
 https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover.

Answer (score 2):

I too was having the same situation and i have done this by using LeveyPopListView.
https://github.com/levey/LeveyPopListView

Try this one.

Answer (score 1):

Make your own `UIView` which should have `UITableView` and Arrow image. Implement custom `init` method which will accept `CGRect` and from that rect display that Arrow image.